# Parsing using mrss

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse an mrss feed using jquery but am having some difficulty targeting the  child element.

Code:

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function(){
   var $item = $(this);
   alert($item.find("media\\:thumbnail").text();
});
```

MRSS Structure:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://somewebsite.com/someimage.jpg" />
```

UPDATE
The solution $item.find("media\:thumbnail").attr("url") works very well in Firefox but running the code in Chrome reveals an undefined value. Can someone suggest a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to display the text() of your found nodes.  The example node you include has no text at all.  You want the value of the url attribute:

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function(){
    var $item = $(this);
    alert($item.find("media\\:thumbnail").attr("url"));
});
```

If your media:thumbnail element had something between opening and closing tags you could use text() (and you still wouldn't be getting the url value):

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://somesite.com/simeimage.jpg">Some text string</media:thumbnail>
```

Comment: I find that when I try to call this image value in Chrome it doesn't show up. Neither Chrome nor Safari respect this format. Would anyone know why?. It works very well in Firefox however.

Comment: What do you mean by "call this image value"?  What are you trying to do, display the image in your HTML?  To get your question answered you should edit your question and add a note indicating "Update" and what you are trying to do.  You also don't include any full XML that we can use to help you with your issue.

Comment: Sorry about at that Tony, I added the update. The $item.find("media\\:thumbnail").attr("url") method outputs an undefined value in chrome though it works really well in FireFox and I was just wondering if you could suggest a workaround. Thanks

Comment: For those who maybe curious about how to parse mrss feeds using jquery, please note that JQuery does not have a standard  method for parsing namespaces.As such if you are targeting the media attribute values the alternatives are given below:



(1)  $item.find("media:\\thumbnail").attr("url") or 
(2)  $item.find("nodename=[media:thumbnail]").attr("url") 

I personally prefer option 2 which works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks for the help Tony much obliged.

Comment: The correct format is $item.find("[nodeName=media:thumbnail]");  Ignore the previous formats